# Regular expression to get a number on a line

Tags: regex, perl

I have to add some easy lines to Perl, and I don't exactly get the regular expressions and how I have to use it.
I run a file and get the input from there:

```
open myFile, "csh ........
```

I run over the lines of the file output by doing "`print`", and I see one of the lines is:

```
TaskID:             1000
```

(there are plenty of spaces there).
What I want to do, is simply to identify the case were the line begins with `TaskID:` and then get the number into a variable.

In order to identify the line which begins with `TaskID`, I did:

```
if (/TaskID:/) {
```

my questions:

1. The if condition works and it does find when it is the line starts with `TaskID`. But is it the correct way to do it, or is there something better?
2. I don't get how to get the number in this line into a variable.

I tried something like:

```
my $mytask = $1;
```

But, it doesn't get it.
Can you help me understand how to get the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\s+` to match multiple whitespaces and `(\d+)` to match and capture the digits.  Refer to [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).  Here is a self-contained example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^TaskID:\s+(\d+)/) {
        my $task = $1;
        print "$task\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
TaskID:             1000
stuff
TaskID:             700
junk
```

This prints:

```
1000
700
```

Answer (score 4):

`$1` contains the text matched by the first capture (`(...)`). Your pattern has no captures, and thus doesn't set `$1`. Fixed:

```perl
if (/^TaskID:\s*(\d+)/) {
   my $task_id = $1;
   ...
}
```

But I like to avoid using `$1`.

```perl
if ( my ($task_id) = /^TaskID:\s*(\d+)/ ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is a simple filtering task which can be solved with following code

NOTE: run as `./script.pl data_file`

- while creates a loop over the file
- `<>` reads from a file provided as an argument to the script
- regular expression selects a piece of interest
- `say $1` prints captured data to a screen

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

/^TaskID:\s+(\d+)/ && say $1 while <>;
```